# Why an enriched natural transformation really is enriched natural.

Tags: category-theory

first of all, please forgive me for linking directly to Google Books here. The statement is just very long, and the specific point I am curious about is not clear to me.

At page 341 of Francis Borceux's Handbook of categorical algebra, Vol II, [see here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5i2v9q0m5XAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=follows%20immediately%20from%20the%20definition%20of%20the&f=false), I am fine with all the details, except the last part. Exactly why does the naturality follow from the V-functor struture of G?

Comment: Do you mean, why does Diagram 6.43 commute? Just expand the definition of $G$ given earlier.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, thanks . I tried to do that but I couldnt work out the details, would you mind expanding it somewhat at least? If you post it as an answer I will of course accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really straightforward (if tedious). First, note that $\theta^{-1}_{A, B}$ is $\mathcal{V}$-natural in $A$ because $\theta_{A, B}$ is. Thus,
$$c_{G C, G B, A} \circ (\theta^{-1}_{G B, C} \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \theta^{-1}_{A, C} \circ c_{C, F G B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes F)$$
Now, using $\mathcal{V}$-naturality of $\theta_{A, B}$ in $B$ and enriched associativity, we have the following: 
\begin{align}
\theta_{A, C} \circ c_{G C, G B, A} \circ (G \otimes \mathrm{id})
& = \theta_{A, C} \circ c_{G C, G B, A} \circ ((\theta^{-1}_{G B, C} \circ \mathcal{B}(\mathrm{id}, \eta_B) ) \otimes \mathrm{id}) \\
& = \theta_{A, C} \circ \theta^{-1}_{A, C} \circ c_{C, F G B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes F) \circ (\mathcal{B}(\mathrm{id}, \eta_B) \otimes \mathrm{id}) \\
& = c_{C, F G B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes F) \circ (\mathcal{B}(\mathrm{id}, \eta_B) \otimes \mathrm{id}) \\
& = c_{C, F G B, F A} \circ (\mathcal{B}(\mathrm{id}, \eta_B) \otimes \mathrm{id})\circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes F) \\
& = c_{C, F G B, F A} \circ (c_{C, B, F G B} \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes (\theta_{G B, B} \circ u_{G B}) \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes F) \\
& = c_{C, B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes c_{B, F G B, F A}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes \theta_{G B, B} \otimes F) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes u_{G B} \otimes \mathrm{id}) \\
& = c_{C, B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes \theta_{A, B}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes c_{G B, G B, A}) \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes u_{G B} \otimes \mathrm{id}) \\
& = c_{C, B, F A} \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes \theta_{A, B})
\end{align}

Finally, some general advice: when trying to prove these basic things, always start by thinking about the case $\mathcal{V} = \mathbf{Set}$ and working out how to phrase the usual proof in this element-free language.

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for your advice - I will try that in the future. This is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Just one thing: $\theta^{-1}_{A,B}$ should be natural in A, not in B, right? I.e when you say that "First, note that $\theta^{-1}_{A,B}$ is $\mathcal{V}$-natural in $B$ because $\theta_{A,B}$ is." you mean to say that the naturality is in A?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry!

Comment: from the second row to the third row, you have $c_{c,FGB,FA}$ and from that you go to $c_{C,B,FA}$ - what does this follow from?

Comment: Wrong subscripts. You can work out what the correct subscripts are if you write out all the domains and codomains.

Comment: Another, unrelated question: How much practice with enriched categories would you advise one to get? My problem is the following: I see the general approach on how to show it, but I get lost in dropping different indices etc. Of course, this is how it was when I started learning (unenriched) category theory but I kept being very precise until' it felt as if I didn't need to. Is something similar here recommended+

Comment: That's up to you, I suppose. My impression is that working category theorists avoid writing down the details if the idea is clear, simply to avoid getting buried in notational issues. Certainly that's what I do.

Comment: Ok! Just one last thing (please, tell me if i am bothering you too much with these questions) : the equality where you write $(id \otimes c_{B,FGB,FA}) \circ (id \otimes \theta_{GB,B} \otimes F) = (id \otimes \theta_{A,B} ) \circ (id \otimes c_{GB,GB,A}$ -what does this follow from?

Comment: Enriched naturality of $\theta$.